# Modelando banco de dados de oferta de ensino

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou estudando banco de dados e cheguei em um problema que não estou conseguindo sair dele. O problema é:

*"Uma escola realiza ofertas de nível de ensino anualmente. A cada ano,  um ou mais níveis de ensino (ensino medio, ensino fundamental) são ofertados. Cada nível de ensino pode ser ofertado em diferentes turnos (matutino, vespertino etc). Cada turno possui ofertas de diferentes séries do nível de ensino (por exemplo, 1ª série do ensino médio pode ser ofertado tanto noturno quanto vespertino; 8º ano do ensino fundamental pode ser ofertada somente noturno). Além disso, cada série possui diferentes turmas. Sendo assim, elabore um banco de dados para para as ofertas anuais".*

Pensando nesse contexto, eu modelei as primeiras tabelas conforme a imagem abaixo. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo criar uma lógica para modelar a parte das ofertas anuais da escola.

As tabelas que eu criei até então são para armazenar os valores de níveis de ensino, série, turno e os relacionamentos n:n.

Se alguém puder me ajudar nessa lógica de como modelar a parte de oferta, eu agradeço.

**IMAGEM**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Ao observar o seu modelo vejo alguns problemas como por exemplo:

- A partir da tabela 'Turma', aparentemente não é possível saber a qual escola ela pertence, assim como também não é possível saber em que ano determinada turma existiu. Parte do seu problema poderia ser sanado ao existir um relacionamento com a tabela 'Oferta', mas creio que ainda assim essa não é a melhor solução para seu problema.

Então tomei um pouco de tempo para tentar fazer uma representação básica de uma modelagem (sem a presença dos atributos) que melhor se encaixe no seu problema, espero que consiga compreender:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E supondo que só vá existir os níveis fundamental e médio, penso que, as três tabelas da parte inferior podem se tornar uma única, pois não vejo a necessidade de existir uma tabela para guardar os níveis e conter somente 2 registros, deste modo os registros na tabela 'SerieEscolar' poderiam conter um atributo que ao invés de guardar um id de nível de ensino, informasse explicitamente o nivel deixando os registros como algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom...espero que tenha entendido o que eu quis lhe dizer, e qualquer dúvida é só questionar.